# Meteor allowing me to subscribe from anywhere, security flaw

Tags: security, meteor, ddp

So I have made a meteor app and I have the autopublish and insecure packages removed, now in order to receive data from my collections I have to subscribe to them in the client. I also have a python program that communicates with my meteor server over ddp using the [python-meteor](https://github.com/hharnisc/python-meteor) package, in it I simply subscribe to my collections and have complete access to all my data, I can also make Meteor.calls to call functions on the server. This is nice but I can't help but feel like this is a major security hole, anyone can write a client and subscribe to my collections and grab all my data on a whim, if they guess the collection names right.

Is there a way to only let certain clients subscribe to collections and perform server calls?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you should add security checks to all publishers and methods.

Here's an example publisher that ensures the user is logged in and is a member of the group before receiving any posts related to the group:

```js
Meteor.publish('postsForGroup', function(groupId) {
  check(groupId, String);

  // make sure the user is a member of the group
  var group = Groups.findOne(groupId);
  if (!_.contains(group.members, this.userId))
    throw new Meteor.Error(403, 'You must be a member of the group!');

  return Posts.find({groupId: groupId});
});
```

Here's an example method that ensures the user is logged in and an admin of the group before being allowed to change the group's name:

```js
Meteor.methods({
  'groups.update.name': function(groupId, name) {
    check(groupId, String);
    check(name, String);

    // make sure the user is an admin of the group
    var group = Groups.findOne(groupId);
    if (!_.contains(group.admins, this.userId))
      throw new Meteor.Error(403, 'You must be an admin of the group!');

    // make sure the name isn't empty
    if (!name.length)
      throw new Meteor.Error(403, 'Name can not be empty!');

    return Groups.update(groupId, {$set: {name: name}});
  }
});
```

---

One detail to watch out for: If you are using iron router, be careful not to **cause** any errors in your publishers. Doing so, will cause `waitOn` to never return. If you think that throwing an error is possible under normal operation, then I'd recommend `return this.ready()` instead of `throw new Meteor.Error` in your publisher.

Comment: Perfect, thank you. Believe it or not I was just reading your "common meteor mistakes" article, very helpful.

Comment: Excellent - I'm glad it was helpful. :)